# How can I send a succesfull TransactWriteItemCommand in AWS-SDK v3 for nodejs?

Tags: transactions, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I'm sending a [TransactWriteItemCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/dynamodb/command/TransactWriteItemsCommand/) to DynamoDB using AWS-SDK v3 in nodejs.
I'm using just one PUT command.

I'm getting a TypeError (see below).

I can`t find the bug, everything looks good to me.

Please help.

```
    const {
        DynamoDBClient,
        TransactWriteItemsCommand,
    } = require('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb');

    const { DynamoDBDocumentClient } = require('@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb');

    let options = {
        maxRetries: 3,
        httpOptions: {
            timeout: 5000,
        },
    };

    const client = new DynamoDBClient(options) 

    const input = { 
           TransactItems:[
              { 
                Put: { 
                   TableName: "my-table-name",
                   Item: {
                      PK: "myPK",
                      SK: "mySK",
                      name: "aname",
                      code: "acode",
                      price: 200,
                      createdAt: "2023-11-07T13:36:12.045Z",
                      updatedAt: "2023-11-07T13:36:12.045Z"
                   }
                }
              }
           ]
         } 
    const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

    ddbDocClient.send(new TransactWriteItemsCommand(input))
```

Here are the logs:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
        at AttributeValue.visit (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/models/models_0.js:632:40)
        at se_AttributeValue (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:2948:38)
        at /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3336:20
        at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
        at se_PutItemInputAttributeMap (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3332:34)
        at Item (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3311:22)
        at applyInstruction (/var/task/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/object-mapping.js:73:33)
        at take (/var/task/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/object-mapping.js:44:9)
        at se_Put (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3307:37)
        at Put (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3479:21),
    response: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue

You have 2 issues in your code:

- You create a client called `client`, but then proceed to call the API using an unknown client called: `ddbDocClient`.
- You are using DocumentClient (high level) syntax, but only import the low level client.

#### Solution 1

Import the document client, where you can continue to use native JSON

```
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { DynamoDBDocumentClient, TransactWriteCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");

let options = {
    maxRetries: 3,
    httpOptions: {
        timeout: 5000,
    },
};

const client = new DynamoDBClient(options);
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);


const input = {
    TransactItems: [
        {
            Put: {
                TableName: "Test",
                Item: {
                    PK: "myPK",
                    SK: "mySK",
                    name: "aname",
                    code: "acode",
                    price: 200,
                    createdAt: "2023-11-07T13:36:12.045Z",
                    updatedAt: "2023-11-07T13:36:12.045Z"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

docClient.send(new TransactWriteCommand(input))
```

#### Solution 2

Change your code to :

`client.send(new TransactWriteItemsCommand(input))`

While doing that, you will also have to change your syntax to the low level client and add type descriptors.

More info on the differences of clients: [Exploring DynamoDB Clients](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/)

Comment: Sorry, I made an error when writing the question, the code was incomplete that's why ddbDocClient didn't exist, i edited now it's correct, that wasn't the issue it still doesn't work

Comment: Please use the example I shared, it works.

Comment: Thank you it worked! The only thing I had to do is change from  "TransactWriteItemsCommand" imported from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb" to "TransactWriteCommand" imported "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb".